# discord.py listen to voice

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, voice

Will there ever be a official way to listen to voice in discord.py, or a reliable way. I have found some forks on github of people making there own, but is there any good, or will there be a official one?

Comment: The further development of `discord.py` has been stopped. Answers to this question will rather be based on own opinion or recommendations.

Comment: @Dominik aw, for real? So we can no longer can create Discord bot in Python?

Comment: You can still create a discord bot, the library is just not being updated anymore. Everything still works fine...

Comment: Ah, ok. I noticed that the Discord bot changes only affects 75+ server bot. Still fine for my use case, then. That is, until Discord Bot API changes to be incompatible with the latest released version of discord.py.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`discord.py` developing has ended during `2021` so, since until now no voice listener has been implemented, there won't be a discord.py way to make bots listen voices.

Anyway, according to the mantainer [`Rapptz`](https://github.com/Rapptz), the bots will continue to work fine [even after `April 2022`](https://dev.to/abhijithganesh/end-of-discord-py-58pc#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20maintainer%2C%20Discord,fine%20even%20after%20April%202022.), but after that all the discord.py developers may need to migrate to a new tecnology.

The organization called [`Nextcord`](https://github.com/nextcord) on GitHub is mantaining a fork of `Rapptz`'s `discord.py` in [`this repository`](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord), but listening to voices is not that easy, and since they are just "[mantaining](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)" I'm pretty sure they will never add this useful feature.